# Variable use in VHDL

Tags: variables, signals, vhdl

I was reading some codes in VHDL and saw this example:

```
  signal     count : integer range 0 to width;
begin
  process(clk, rst)
    variable temp  : integer range 0 to width;
begin
          temp := count + 1;
          count <= temp;
end process;
```

what's the purpose of count signal here? Why can't we just use the variable?

Comment: Did you mean why can't you use the signal?  The variable is local only to the process and other processes cannot use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are local to the process, and signals are used to communicate between processes.

So you would rather do without the variable, and in the process just have:

```
count <= count + 1;
```

Comment: so is the variable basically just useless here?

Comment: My guess is that there is more to the code than what you have shown, since the sensitivity list has `(clk, rst)`, which indicates a clocked process, where the details are not shown.  In that case, the variable may be used for various reasons.  But if the shown code is all there is, then the variable can be eliminated, through the code make little sense.